# handle crash of flask app on database restart

Tags: postgresql, flask, psycopg2

Currently have made a flask application which crashes when I do a postgres database restart, because the cursor which was opened is stale ...

How do I handle this situation. Currently connecting the flask app to postgres via psycopg2....

I am not a database expert...

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/www/flaskapps/capp/override.py", line 15, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1356, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1539, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 321, in _load_user
    self.reload_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 350, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/var/www/flaskapps/capp/login_setup.py", line 163, in load_user
    cursor.execute(qstr)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/psycopg2/extras.py", line 123, in execute
    return _cursor.execute(self, query, vars)
InterfaceError: cursor already closed
```

Comment: Try using Flask-SQLAlchemy with Posgres

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many cases where your code needs to detect a transient failure and re-try the transaction, re-opening the connection if necessary.

Other cases include deadlocks and serialization failures.

The sqlstate on the exception will let you determine which error cases to retry and how. See [the PostgreSQL documentation on error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) for guidance on the meaning of the sqlstate codes.

Sometimes your database interface will through a typed exception that tells you enough just by its data type, too. This doesn't look like one of those cases.